# How to work with OS map files from Digimap?

Tags: qgis, raster

I am trying to add map tiles as raster files in QGIS but when I add them they all appear on top of each other. I did this once before and everything was ok but I am now unable to find how to get the tiles showing as one map. I am using OS Streetview.

Answer (score 1):

If you have just downloaded OS StreetView, note that files comes in two folders, 'georeferencing files' and 'SN' (or other index). This means that for whatever reasons OS decided to keep georeferencing information separate from maps.

Before loading maps in QGIS, you need to move TFW files from 'georeferencing' into 'sn' folder.

To check if QGIS recognized georeferencing information, use Raster\Miscellaneous\Information for the map you've added.

Raster without georeferencing info will show this:

[image: no georeferencing]

Comment: The data was downloaded as a zip file and the folder shows tif files and tfw files. There are no other folders in it. I'm sure when I did this before I just used the tif files and everything was fine but cannot work out what/if I am doing anything different.

Comment: Just to add the files were downloaded from Digimap if that makes a difference

Comment: I guess it does. My answer was using data downloaded from OS at www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/products/os-streetview/index.html Please add one of the maps and check was Information says are there coordinates or only pixels like in example above?

Comment: I downloaded from OS and problem now solved. Thanks very much for your help. Much appreciated.